# Помогите подобрать инструмент для рисования графа

Tags: java, android, graph

Необходимо реализовать следующую активность:

---

1. При переходе на неё мы видим пустой холст(Сразу же вопрос, что это может быть? Canvas? Если да, то возможно ли на нём реализовать то, что будет описано далее?)
2. При нажатии на холст будет создано Ядро(на второй картинке по центру), и снова вопрос, что это может быть за элемент? Как реализовать какую-то свою готовую библиотеку?
3. Далее от этого ядра будут создаваться в виде ветвящегося дерева записи, отображающие поля класса, причем каждая из них автоматически соединятся стрелкой с родителем(у этой стрелки будет возможность подсвечиваться в зависимости от определённых условий, так сказать прокладывать путь)

+все объекты помимо ядра будет возможно перетащить, а стрелки будут автоматически следовать за ними.

**Собственно основной вопрос:**
Какие инструменты использовать для решения задачи? Как и с помощью чего подготовить какую-то свою либу готовых элементов? На чём они будут отображаться? И как сделать умные стрелки которые сами следуют за объектами, при это с возможностью подсветки(возможно анимация).
[image: Поясняющая картинка]

Comment: 1 Можно View перегрузить и рисовать на Canvas. 2 Создать дерево объектов и отрисовывать их и связи примитивами.

Comment: А как рисовать свой view на canvas? Гуглю второй день и видимо из-за недостатка знаний в этой теме не понимаю какой конкретно инструмент мне нужен. 
А так же как сделать Canvas бОльшим, чем экран, чтоб сделать его перемещаемым и масштабируемым?